# Example of random walk in a random environment (RWRE) saying things on the environment

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, random-walks, random-graphs

I was wondering if anyone is aware of works/articles/examples where random walks in a random environment (RWRE) are actually used for obtaining information on the random environment.

To clarify a bit, maybe an example of an answer could be a work where someone wants to obtain information on a percolation model though the behavior of a RW on the induced random graph. I would be surprised such an example exists, but you never know.

So still loose but short: are there examples where RWREs are used as a tool to study the underlying environment but not as an object of study by itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example: Matzinger studied the revocery of the environment from the second factor of a RWRE.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.6853.pdf
https://matzi.math.gatech.edu/overview.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A couple of "one-dimensional" examples: https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.6328 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.00101